# Outer measure of rationals between 0 and 1. Royden.

Tags: real-analysis, outer-measure

I've been studying Royden and I have found something that looks like a contradiction to me, and can't find where it is that my reasoning is wrong. On Chapter 3 he defines the outer measure $m^*$ of a set $A$ as:

$m^*A = \inf_{A \subset I_n} \sum l(I_n)$

where $\{I_n\}$ is a countable collection of open intervals, and $l$ is the length.

What troubles me is that corollary 3 on chapter 3 says: "If $A$ is countable, $m^*A = 0$". And right bellow problem 5 states: "Let $A$ be the set of rational numbers between 0 and 1, and let $\{I_n\}$ be a finite collection of open intervals covering $A$. Then $\sum l(I_n) \geq 1$".

My question is, how can every open covering of the rationals between 0 and 1 have length grater or equal to 1 if at the same time, by virtue of being countable, the outer measure of the rationals is 0 (corollary 3) and hence:

$m^*(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]) = \inf_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset I_n}\sum l(I_n) = 0$.

Isn't there a contradiction in saying $\inf_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset I_n} \sum l(I_n) = 0$, and for all $\{I_n\}$, $\sum l(I_n) \ge 1$?

Comment: Why did this get a -1? This is a very reasonable question - the difference between properties of finite and infinite covers is subtle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important difference between the two is that one covering is allowed to be countable, while the other is finite. The fact that allowing countable coverings gives $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ measure 0 is the same as for all other countable sets; that a finite covering has measure at least 1 is a good exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
How would you construct a countable covering of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ such that the measure of the covering is zero?

Answer (score 2):

For the "finite covering has measure at least 1 is a good exercise" part from @de Vries answer, OP can have a look at [Bass] page 29; Lemma 4.7 solves that exercise.